# NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData changing contents of returned results?

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
func retrieveData(englishWord : String, completionHandler : (success: Bool, data : [String : AnyObject]?, errorString : String?) -> Void) {
        let baseURL = "https://api.pearson.com/v2/dictionaries/ldoce5/entries?headword=vodka"
        let urlString = baseURL
        print(urlString)
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                completionHandler(success: false, data: nil, errorString: "There was a networking error")
                return
            }
            if data == nil {
                completionHandler(success: false, data: nil, errorString: "There was an error in the request for data")
                return
            }

            let parsedResult : AnyObject?
            do {
                parsedResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                print(parsedResult!)

            } catch {
                completionHandler(success: false, data: nil, errorString: "There was an error in the conversion for data")
                return
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

So right now `print(parsedResult!)` gives:

> {
>       count = 1;
>       limit = 10;
>       offset = 0;
>       results =     (
>                   {
>               datasets =             (
>                   ldoce5,
>                   dictionary
>               );
>               headword = vodka;
>               id = cqAG3cXCxZ;
>               "part_of_speech" = noun;
>               pronunciations =             (
>                                   {
>                       audio =                     (
>                                                   {
>                               lang = "British English";
>                               type = pronunciation;
>                               url = "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/vodka0205.mp3";
>                           }
>                       );
>                       ipa = "\U02c8v\U0252dk\U0259";
>                   },
>                                   {
>                       audio =                     (
>                                                   {
>                               lang = "American English";
>                               type = pronunciation;
>                               url = "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/us_pron/vodka.mp3";
>                           }
>                       );
>                       ipa = "\U02c8v\U0251\U02d0dk\U0259";
>                       lang = "American English";
>                   }
>               );
>               senses =             (
>                                   {
>                       definition =                     (
>                           "a strong clear alcoholic drink originally from Russia, or a glass of this"
>                       );
>                   }
>               );
>               url = "/v2/dictionaries/entries/cqAG3cXCxZ";
>           }
>       );
>       status = 200;
>       total = 1;
>       url = "/v2/dictionaries/ldoce5/entries?headword=vodka";
>   }

But the query URL : [Here](https://api.pearson.com/v2/dictionaries/ldoce5/entries?headword=vodka)

I posted it here for convenience:

> {"status":200,"offset":0,"limit":10,"count":1,"total":1,"url":"/v2/dictionaries/ldoce5/entries?headword=vodka","results":[{"datasets":["ldoce5","dictionary"],"headword":"vodka","id":"cqAG3cXCxZ","part_of_speech":"noun","pronunciations":[{"audio":[{"lang":"British English","type":"pronunciation","url":"/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/vodka0205.mp3"}],"ipa":"ˈvɒdkə"},{"audio":[{"lang":"American English","type":"pronunciation","url":"/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/us_pron/vodka.mp3"}],"ipa":"ˈvɑːdkə","lang":"American English"}],"senses":[{"definition":["a strong clear alcoholic drink originally from Russia, or a glass of this"]}],"url":"/v2/dictionaries/entries/cqAG3cXCxZ"}]}

Is there a reason why `NSJSONSerialization` is changing my data as the data printed out is clearly different to what is returned by the Pearson API?

Comment: The only difference that i can see is bracket notation for array type which is represented by [ in the API and ( in the serialization. You can still parse it to your object then. And another difference is `ˈvɒdkə` from your API and `\U02c8v\U0251\U02d0dk\U0259` in printed result. You may need to encoding the result with the appropriate encode type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's actually changing the values, I believe you're just looking at a different representation.  (If Swift behaves like Objective-C), the print(x) will call the "description" method on x, which can output the object in any format it likes to.

What you might want to do is reencode the data using: dataWithJSONObject:options:error (the essentially opposite call to what you made), and take a look at what the representation is.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error:

Comment: I can't re-encode the data as it says that the top-level Object isn't an Array or Dictionary but I printed it in the logs and from the webpage it is obviously an Dictionary any ideas?